# Refactor SQL query to return results into rows instead of columns

Tags: sql, refactoring

I have a SQL query that need to be refactored. Basically the query gets all the producttypes  ordered by a specified customer. The problem is that the results are returned in columns instead of rows. This needs to be changed the other way around to make the query more generic.

**So this is what the query returns:**

```
Name   ProductType1   ProductType2   ProductType3
--------------------------------------------------
Marc   PT09           P15            PT33
```

**And this is what it should be:**

```
Name ProductType
----------------
Marc PT09
Marc P15
Marc PT33
```

**This is the query which I have simplified a bit:**

```
SELECT 
      CustomerData.Name as Name
      Product1.productType as ProductType1,
      Product2.productType as ProductType2,
      Product3.productType as ProductType3
FROM
    (SELECT ProductID, Name
            FROM 
                Customer 
                Orders
      WHERE Customer.ID = 111
    ) as CustomerData

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CP.ProductID as ProductID,
                           PC.Type as ProductType
           FROM 
                CustomerProduct CP,
                ProductCategory PC
           WHERE
                PC.Category = 'A'
                AND CP.ProductCategoryID = PC.ID
           )  as Product1
           on CustomerData.ProductID = Product1.ProductID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CP.ProductID as ProductID,
                           PC.Type as ProductType
           FROM 
                CustomerProduct CP,
                ProductCategory PC
           WHERE
                PC.Category = 'B'
                AND CP.ProductCategoryID = PC.ID
           )  as Product2
           on CustomerData.ProductID = Product1.ProductID

LEFT JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT CP.ProductID as ProductID,
                           PC.Type as ProductType
           FROM 
                CustomerProduct CP,
                ProductCategory PC
           WHERE
                PC.Category = 'C'
                AND CP.ProductCategoryID = PC.ID
           )  as Product3
           on CustomerData.ProductID = Product1.ProductID
```

So I have been thinking about splitting the joins into a separate stored proc and then call this as I need more productTypes but I can't seem to get this working. Anyone an idea on how to get this working ?

Comment: Is number of product types known before You're executing the query? If so, You could dynamically create SQL with multiple UNIONs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Doing things in columns is actually usually much more difficult.

Assuming normalized tables Customers, Products and Orders, you shouldn't need to do anything more than just:

```
SELECT C.customer_name
     , P.product_type
FROM Customers C
  JOIN Orders O
    ON O.customer_id=C.customer_id
  JOIN Products P
    ON O.product_id=P.product_id
WHERE C.ID = 111
```

If this doesn't work, please list structures of the involved tables.

Comment: +1 Yep, that's the way to do it. It may only need `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN`, depending on his data and what he wants to show. Or maybe a `GROUP BY` if customer has many orders of the same product and you just want to see one row for any of those (orders). Or one more join if he wants to show or filter on ProductCategory as well. But this is the way to go. Plus the query looks simple and elegant: less than 10 lines of code instead of the 40+ complex one with 4 subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume your tables looks something like this

Customer

```
id | name
11 | Marc
```

Products

```
id | type
21 | PT09
22 | P15
23 | PT33
```

Orders

```
id | id_customer | id_product | quantity
31 | 11          | 21         | 4
32 | 11          | 22         | 6
33 | 11          | 23         | 8
```

Then your query is

```
SELECT 
    a.name,
    c.type
FROM 
    Customer a
LEFT JOIN 
    Orders b ON b.id_customer = a.id
LEFT JOIN 
    Products c ON c.id = b.id_product
```